# QGIS - Processing framework - QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource type

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I use `QGIS` to build a script with processing framework. In processing toolbox menu I wan't to "filter" data with data types. I can filter point/line/polygon vector layer but how can I filter layers without geometry ? For example a `CSV` file ?

When I try `QgsProcessing.TypeVector`, I can see all layers, with or without geometry, such as `QgsProcessing.TypeFile`. What their differences ?

Some examples:

```
# Point vector layer
self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.LAYER_POINT,
                self.tr('Point layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint]
            )
        )
# Line vector layer
self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.LAYER_LINE,
                self.tr('Line layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]
            )
        )
# All files
self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.LAYER_VECTOR,
                self.tr('Vector layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVector]
            )
        )
# All files also
self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.LAYER_FILE,
                self.tr('File layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeFile]
            )
        )
```

Sources: [QgsProcessing](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessing.html), [QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource.html#module-QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource), [QgsProcessing::SourceType](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessing.html#acad4d2322342455b53eee5701e2b3115)